# How to intergrate AEM with hybris?

Tags: aem, sap-commerce-cloud

In my project i want to establish connection to hybris and get data from there. And print  that data in AEM.

How to i do it and how to connect to hybris ?

Comment: Have you read this article? https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ecommerce/hybris.html

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions.

One would be to use hybris OCC Webservice. hybris exposes one WS to retrieve the full content of a product catalog and an other to retrieve only the delta using a timestamp as reference.

In your osgi configuration you will find the url to configure it should be something like `/rest/v2/mysite/products/export/full`